# Xampp localhost Strict Standards error

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

Even I changed php.ini file. 
I changed php.ini 
the default is:

```
; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

I change them into:

```
 display_startup_errors
   Default Value: Off
   Development Value: On
   Production Value: Off

 error_reporting
   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

I still keep getting the following errors:

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of CUser::Save() should be compatible with that of CBase::Save() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\user.class.php on line 128
Strict Standards: Declaration of CUser::Add() should be compatible with that of CBase::Add() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\user.class.php on line 128
Strict Standards: Declaration of CUser::Edit() should be compatible with that of CBase::Edit() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\user.class.php on line 128
Strict Standards: Declaration of CNewsLetter::Save() should be compatible with that of CBase::Save() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\newsletter.class.php on line 89
Strict Standards: Declaration of CNewsLetter::Add() should be compatible with that of CBase::Add() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\newsletter.class.php on line 89
Strict Standards: Declaration of CNewsLetter::Edit() should be compatible with that of CBase::Edit() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\newsletter.class.php on line 89
Strict Standards: Declaration of CLanguage::UpdateSEO() should be compatible with that of CBase::UpdateSEO() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\language.class.php on line 186
Strict Standards: Declaration of CNav::Save() should be compatible with that of CBase::Save() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\nav.class.php on line 178
Strict Standards: Declaration of CNav::Edit() should be compatible with that of CBase::Edit() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\nav.class.php on line 178
Strict Standards: Declaration of CDatabase::GetAll() should be compatible with that of CBase::GetAll() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\database.class.php on line 119
Strict Standards: Declaration of CNews::GetMaxOrder() should be compatible with that of CBase::GetMaxOrder() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\news.class.php on line 160
Strict Standards: Declaration of CNews::UpdateOrder() should be compatible with that of CBase::UpdateOrder() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\news.class.php on line 160
Strict Standards: Declaration of CNavigation::GetMaxOrder() should be compatible with that of CBase::GetMaxOrder() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\navigation.class.php on line 75
Strict Standards: Declaration of CNavigation::UpdateOrder() should be compatible with that of CBase::UpdateOrder() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\navigation.class.php on line 75
Strict Standards: Declaration of CArticle::GetMaxOrder() should be compatible with that of CBase::GetMaxOrder() in D:\xampp\htdocs\web\newpacific\include\article.class.php on line 117
```

Thanks in advance. I searched in the forum. didnt figure out why it still getting strict standard errors

Comment: plus since ; in php.ini is for comment a line. I changed into the following                                                           ; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off
display_startup_errors = Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE                                   But Its still getting the strict error. please help me

Comment: You should re-comment those lines, if you look at the text before them it probably says "Please see the actual settings later in the document" because they aren't the setting, but just suggestions. You should see a line later that says "display_startup_errors = Off" or something similar that is one of the settings. Set them and restart the server.

Comment: as craniumonempty said, you should comment those lines. The lines just tell you the default values(if none is specified explicitly), value you should use on production server (Production Value) and value you should use on development server (Development Value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@craniumonempty I renamed php.ini into other name, then renamed php.ini-development file into php.ini Now no errors anymore. Hope This could help someone

Or change error_reporting into `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED`

Answer (score 1):

Tested it out on xampp (didn't have it, so just wanted to see) and setting "`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`" in php.ini gets rid of that strict warning. Remember to restart server (and comment the lines that you uncommented) for it to take effect.

Also, you can also make sure that the functions are meeting the standards as well. Something I found online:

```
class ParentClass
 {
        protected static function foo($param1, $param2)
         {
                echo "Parent\n";
         }
 }

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
 {
        public static function foo($param1)
         {
                parent::foo($param1, 2);
                echo "Child\n";
         }
 }

ChildClass::foo(1);
```

This triggers a standard, because foo doesn't match the other foo, but you can simply put:

```
        public static function foo($param1, $param2=2)
         {
                parent::foo($param1, 2);
                echo "Child\n";
         }
```

and either use $param2 or ignore it to get rid of the warning, but if taken, I would use it...

Comment: I changed them into the following display_errors = Off display_startup_errors = Off error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED others are commented, restarted the server, but still got the strict standards error. what did i do wrong?

Comment: @Nick I can't open it right now, so tell me the version of xampp you are running. I'll try to dup it later. Also, try to make sure xampp isn't overwritting the php.ini. Maybe it's loading the production file instead. I'll try to get on that when I get the chance.

Comment: I renamed php.ini into other name, then renamed php.ini-development file into php.ini  Now no errors anymore. Hope This could help someone

Comment: @Nick, good. Sorry I haven't gotten back to it. You can create the answer and then accept it so that the question gets solved in the queue.